# MySQL: Column Contains Word From List of Words

Tags: sql, mysql, innodb

I have a list of words. Lets say they are 'Apple', 'Orange', and 'Pear'. I have rows in the database like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
|author_id   |  content                        |
------------------------------------------------
| 54         | I ate an apple for breakfast.   |
| 63         | Going to the store.             |
| 12         | Should I wear the orange shirt? |
------------------------------------------------
```

I'm looking for a query on an InnoDB table that will return the 1st and 3rd row, because the `content` column contains one or more words from my list. I know I could query the table once for each word in my list, and use LIKE and the % wildcard character, but I'm wondering if there is a single query method for such a thing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE content LIKE '%apple%' OR content LIKE '%orange%'
```

You can loop your words to create WHERE clause conditions.

**For Example:**

```
$words = array( 'apple', 'orange' );
$whereClause = '';
foreach( $words as $word) {
   $whereClause .= ' content LIKE "%' . $word . '%" OR';
}

// Remove last 'OR'
$whereClause = substr($whereClause, 0, -2);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE' . $whereClause;

echo $sql;
```

[**Output:**](http://codepad.org/wpHHdmCy)

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE content LIKE "%apple%" OR content LIKE "%orange%"
```

Comment: uh, I was apparently late and yours is more complete, so I guess you'll get a +1.

Comment: This is what I'm doing now, and I was hoping to avoid it. While it does avoid the network overhead of separate queries, I would assume that MySQL is internally running running each word over every row in the table, which is essentially several queries. I was hoping MySQL had an optimized function for this type of query.

Answer (score 40):

MySQL (I believe the 5.0 version) added the ability to use regular expressions in your SQL.

Check out:  http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_MySQL_Regular_Expressions.htm

```
SELECT author_id, content
FROM AuthorTableName
WHERE content REGEXP 'Apple|Orange|Pear'
ORDER BY author_id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I need.

Comment: Elegant and this should be the correct answer. I'd guess 5.0 is an acceptable minimal version

Comment: using REGEXP 'Apple.*Orange.*Pear' will yield the results that contain all the words in the specified order.

Comment: This does not bring all the results between the simple quotes to me. And it is by a far cry.

Comment: You made my night, tks.