# Searching for multiple keywords in a string

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to perform an SQL query to find multiple "text1", "text2" in a single string in a particular column and was wondering if someone could help.

Example: Query for: Blue Beige
Column
"Blue and Beige t-shirt"
"Red and Blue t-shirt"
"Red t-shirt"
"Blue t-shirt"

Result should be ONLY "Blue and Beige t-shirt" as it meets the criteria of having for query. Like "%" functions seem to not be useful.

Another example would be query for: "iPhone 256GB"
Column
"iPhone Red 128GB"
"iPhone 256GB"
"iPhone Pro Max 256GB"
"iPhone se 128GB"

Results should be:
"iPhone 256GB"
"iPhone Pro Max 256GB"

please help

Comment: Does the order matter? If so, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4694715/529282 work, if the order doesn't matter, modify https://stackoverflow.com/a/4688665/529282 to use AND instead of OR

Comment: Similar question with answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72223609/particular-column-has-multiple-data-separated-with-comma-how-to-write-a-query-t/72223918#72223918

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for entries that contain each space-separated input regardless of order, so for instance if your search text is "iphone 256" and you want to find any entries that contain both "iphone" and "256" regardless of order, then you would do:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> LIKE '%iphone%' and <column> LIKE '%256%'
```

If you want the results to only include entries where the keywords are in the given order, you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> LIKE '%iphone%256'
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on vball's answer for your Blue Beige search. You could use the same technique, which does include the % wildcard. If the colors can come in any order:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> LIKE '%Blue%' AND <column> LIKE '%Beige%'
```

Comment: If your answer is exactly same and you just want to add an example or something, you can suggest an edit to given answer rather than copying the same as new answer